# Azure Data Factory data flow file sink

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using a .csv file to import data into an Azure SQL database. After the data import is complete I am now moving the source file from the Source container to myArchive container. I am now trying to save the filename as ***SaleData_yyyyMMdd_HHmm.csv***, but,  I have the folder with this name getting created and the file is broken down into multiple part files (part-00000-, part-00001-,...). Could you please guide me on how to specify the filename with current data & timestamp.

File System: myArchive

Folder Path: `concat('SalesDepartment/Warehouse1/','SaleData_',toString(currentTimestamp(),'yyyyMMdd_HHmm'),'.csv')`

[image]

Comment: What task are you using to move it? It sounds like it's saving as parquet. This is still a valid file format but probably not the one you want. Make sure your dataset is CSV not parquet

Comment: So you are using two copy activities? One to copy to SQL table and another to move to archive ?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I have the files saved as .csv but its not using the naming convention that I define. The folder is getting created as `SaleData_yyyyMMdd_HHmm.csv` and the file as `part-0000`.

Comment: @AllAboutBI, Yes, I am using 2 copy activities 1 to copy to the SQL table and the other to archive on to the Data Lake Storage.

Comment: As I said, that folder/part means it's saving as parquet, not csv. So make sure your target dataset is CSV, not parquet

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Sure, Thanks for the clarification as I am still learning the nuances of ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder path can be mentioned directly in the sink dataset. (Note, my source and sink both are delimited type)

For filename,
Under sink data set, create a parameter to pass file name and use it in the file name portion of dataset.

[image: SinkSetting]

Use the below expression in copy activity sink's parameter value

```
@concat('SaleData_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMdd_HHmm'),'.csv')
```

[image: SinkParamValue]

Remember, this just copies your source in a different name. We need to add a delete activity to delete the original source file.

If you are using a dataflow,

make sure you are choosing single partition in the optimize tab of Sink instead of Use current Partitioning.

[image: Partitioningoption]

Then, go to Settings, choose Output to SIngle file. Under filename, mention the expression with timestamp.

```
concat('SaleData_',toString(currentUTC('yyyyMMdd_HHmm')),'.csv')
```

[image: Setting]

Comment: The OP doesn't make it clear but I assume they are using a standard data copy instead of data flows. ADF really needs a simple "Move" and "Copy" activity rather than literally having to do a row by row data copy.

Comment: To avoid "row by row", use Binary dataset type in Copy